# Lubuntu Stuck on "Detecting Network Hardware" in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, toshiba-satellite, virtualbox-networking

I am trying to migrate from Windows to Lubuntu. I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro S300, with 2GB RAM, Intel Core2Duo 1.7GHz CPU.
Virtualbox 5.2.34 setings are: 512MB RAM, 128MB Graphic, 1 CPU.

I've already tried many solutions including different settings for "Network Adapter" and "Boot Options", but the installation process hangs at the "Detecting Network Hardware" step.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me sorry. What release of Lubuntu?  Is this running on hardware? or a VM on the virtualbox you mention. The box doesn't have much memory (but I don't know you release..) and are you talking about an installed system booting? or an ISO booting?

Comment: Well, I've described all in my original text, but it's edited by some dude who I don't know!
Anyway, here it is:
lubuntu 18.04 (LTS) iso image, win 7 32bit, virtualbox 5.2.34, 2GB RAM(512 dedicate to vm), 128 MB graphics memory, intel core2duo 1.5 GHz. CPU.
Regards.

Comment: The editor was trying to help, and yes it cleared up (I didn't look at edit sorry) the fact that you're using a VM, but not if you are talking about an installed system, or a 'live' system that you are trying to install. If it's the latter, did you verify your ISO and if appropriate write to install media (if you were booting from thumb-drive for example, most vbox users don't do this as you can boot from ISO).  Most other issues you'll encounter are HOST OS issues, ie. windows 7 issues which are off-topic here (because they are settings in your old virtualbox 5.2.34 which is done on HOST OS)

Comment: I have to be specific, that my .iso image is exactly 18.04.3-alternate which I attached to optical drive in VB storage settings and when run the Linux/Lubuntu instance that created in VB, it booted and shows me the screen with opt out items to "install lubuntu" and other options. I choose language and keyboard settings, then the installer read CD-ROM (Scan it) load Additional Components, then when try to "Detect Network Hardware" it stucks (but not that it hangs) since the VM is responsive and I can "Close"/"Reset"/... it, so the system is working but the installation process stucks. Any Idea?

Comment: P.S: my VB is a fresh install(no previous settings).